# Project twitter geo data into WGS84 map

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, wgs84, twitter

I'm currently working on displaying twitter geo data (currently just long/lat -> cartesian without any analysis).

This is the world map (source: [naturalearthdata](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/)): http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14747311/world.png

This is the rendered data: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14747311/overlay.png. The mapping is done via [mercator projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) (with R = 1):

```
x = ((long + 180)/360)*x_dim
y = (y_dim/2) - ((arsinh(tan(lat))*(y_dim/2) (lat converted to radiant of course)
```

Now, the shape is apparent, but of course, the projections don't match. How can I fix that? (programming experience is plentiful, so it's more the theoretical side I'm concerned with).

Comment: Are you writing everything from scratch? How did you render the world map? Both Naturalearthdata and Twitter POIs use lat/lon.

Comment: The world map is rendered via mapnik, the twitter data via the detailed equations (using ruby and rmagick). I'm really new to the topic and open to suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried rendering the twitter data over the naturalearthdata without projection? As @underdark says, the data is in lat/long originally. Also, have you tried rendering both sets of data through Mapnik as part of the same image? At worst you take the twitter data and turn it into a [GeoJSON](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_geojson.html) dataset and render through the OGR driver, or a [CSV](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_csv.html)

Comment: How am I'm supposed to render lat/long to a cartesian system without a projection? Also, this is just the first stage, I want to render the information differently, not just single lat/long points, and that is better done in the cartesian system :-/

Comment: Lat/Long are really just x and y coordinates with a range -90<=Lat<=90 and -180<=Long<=180. The image may look distored from what you're used to seeing, but it would still work. (Also, technically, lat/long WGS84 is a cartesian projection based on [geodetic data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_system)). The reason I suggest this is to make sure the data lines up in the first place - if not then you have to look at the data you're getting. If so then project as you wish.

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of that - the equations above are a linear mapping into the cartesian coordinates of image, so that's not really the problem. I don't necessarily need to do the world map via mapnik, neither does it have to be exact, just the shape of the continents has to be vaguely correct. So if you could point me to some sort of dataset that I could render myself with the same technique I use to render the twitter data, I would be helped as well.

Comment: The world map certainly isn't in Mercator, but probably pseudo-Plate Carree (lat/lon just mapped as if they're linear units) or Plate Carree. Mercator stretches north-south, and you can see that the POIs are offset north and south versus the base map.

Comment: Femaref, @mkennedy has provided the diagnosis (your world map is not in a Mercator projection).  The implied solution is to treat (lon, lat) as (x, y), scaled to your world map (this is the "Plate Carree" projection), and you should get a close match.  No inverse hyperbolic sine functions are needed :-).

Comment: mkennedy: make that an answer and I'll accept it. It puts me way nearer to the solution, even though there is still an offset (probably because the world map isn't a full 90°, but 86° lat) current version (1 mil tweets, about 24h): http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14747311/overlay.png

Comment: look at pyproj, worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "The world map certainly isn't in Mercator, but probably pseudo-Plate Carree (lat/lon just mapped as if they're linear units) or Plate Carree. Mercator stretches north-south, and you can see that the POIs are offset north and south versus the base map." [mkennedy]
>
> "@mkennedy has provided the diagnosis (your world map is not in a Mercator projection). **The implied solution is to treat (lon, lat) as (x, y)**, scaled to your world map (this is the "Plate Carree" projection), and you should get a close match. No inverse hyperbolic sine functions are needed :-)." [whuber]

*Note: This is a summary of comments by @mkennedy and @whuber, so this question can be marked as answered.*

Answer (score 0):

Trends Map works quite well from geotweets using the Twitter Geo API.

*"We are currently processing around **30 million tweets per day**. We have over 1000 cities from around the world that have their own page on the site (eg Melbourne), and the number of topics changes depending on what people are tweeting about."*

Key to this is:

*"Trendsmap uses a large volume of tweets and various algorithms to determine what is trending for a given location"*

http://trendsmap.com/

Comment: That's really fine and all for them but doesn't help me with my problem, considering my problem isn't the data or even twitter (the data could be anything, it just happends to be geodata from twitter as it is readily available), my problem is the projection.

Comment: but Lat/Lng is in WGS84 - this works with openlayers OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913") Google Map OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326") Twitter API